# Too many database updates problem

Tags: php, ajax, oracle

I got a problem with too many updates in a php script. The queries are simple but they're about 300 to 400 at once. I send all the data by ajax and then in php I run a loop to execute the queries. They're like this one:

```
UPDATE APPS.DIB_CUS_FUNDIDOS SET
    R$KG_SINSP_CICMS = 3.85

WHERE
    ID_PRODUTO = 313;
```

So when I run it's never return a answer, never ends and my IE breaks up and I have to close and open again. The queries aren't executed at all.

What I'm looking for is an performance solution. Any ideas ?

Comment: First off, ID_PRODUTO is indexed right? And could you provide more of the surrounding code so that we can understand the bigger picture?

Comment: I didn't created the table, so I asked to dba to create the index and it's solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

300 updates like you made an example should be executed in less than second.

I guess you are missing an index on `ID_PRODUTO`.

Comment: Bulls eye ! An index and a sleep(1) in each 50 updates solved my problem.

Comment: `usleep(100*000);` will do fine too :) It will wait 100ms instead of one second.

Comment: yeah, I'll down the sleep time to maximum to get better performance.